# Using seperate OneToManys to create a ManyToMany Join table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jpa, playframework, ebean

I've got 2 models `User` and `Exercise`. Now any `User` can have any `Exercise`. It's a `ManyToMany` situation. I modeled it with `@ManyToMany`, but you can't have a duplicate entry in a `ManyToMany`. A User is likely to do multiple sets of one exercise so I duplicate entries are required. To get round this I created the join table separately called `UserExerciseJoin`. User and Exercise had `ManyToOne` relationships with the `UserExerciseJoin` model. Though this solved the multiple keys issue I now can't delete from the new table. I get an `OptimisticLockException` from some of the models associated to the `Exercise`.

**My question is**: Am I on the right path with the seperate table or is there something I can do to a standard `@ManyToMany` to make it accept duplicate entries?

Comment: `duplicate entries are required`  how will duplicate entries be useful?

Comment: When someone logs into the app it will return their exercises. In my controller return it will be something like ok{user.exercises}. All entries in that entity can then be mapped in a view. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. You should have `@OneToMany` relation from `User` class and from `Excercise` class to this new entity. And in `UserExerciseJoin` you should have `@ManyToOne` relations.
So this code should look like this:

```
@Entity
User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserExercise> userExercises;

    ....
}

@Entity
Excercise {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="excercise")
    private List<UserExercise> userExercises;

    ....
}

@Entity
UserExercise
{
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Excercise excercise;

    ...
}
```

You had an error when deleting this new entity. You had in on some entity related to excercise. It seems that this is because of cascades. You probably set cascades on fields of UserExerciseJoin class. If it was `CascadeType.DELETE` or `CascadeType.ALL` cascade then it caused deletion of related entities. So you shouldn't set cascades in `UserExercise` class. Then deleting of such entity will not cause a problem.

Comment: Amazing. I'm going to give this a go when I get home. I thought it might have something to do with cascade.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right in your model, then yes, it is probably not the case for @ManyToMany. It seems to me that you can be better off with a **meaningful entity** like `UserExerciseOccurrence` that reference both a `User` and an `Exercise` and means a concrete exercise session.

You can also benefit from this approach if you need to save more info about a particular exercise session (like duration, etc).

```
@Entity
class UserExerciseOccurrence {
   @ManyToOne
   User user;

   @ManyToOne
   Exercise exercise;
}

@Entity
class User {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=DELETE)
   Set<UserExerciseOccurrence> exerciseOccurrences;
}

@Entity
class Exercise {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="exercise", cascade=DELETE)
   Set<UserExerciseOccurrence> exerciseOccurrences;
}
```

Comment: Okay, would the ExerciseOccurence entity have OneToMany non-owning side relationships with both the other entities? Would that cause issues when deleting from the this new entity?

Comment: I would probably make ExerciseOccurrence (or a "training session") the owning side, create a service for managing them. instead of adding/deleting Exercise for the User, i would add/delete ExerciseOccurrence for the User in your service layer.